# Angular how to return value from http.post success?

Tags: http, post, angularjs, return-value

i have a code in my angular controller

```
$scope.message = '';
$http.post('/save/').success(function(data) {                  
    $scope.message = "success";
});
console.log($scope.message);
//get empty string?
```

why after i run, i get empty string on $scope.message? 
how http.post when success return value because i want to reuse the value for my another function. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is this:

```
$scope.$watch("message", function(value){
  console.log($scope.message);
});
```

Here is  [a sample plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cdymfFgfP3UKDqxnl4v4?p=preview) I've made

Comment: i have upload sample http://jsfiddle.net/Gb2pt/7/ i need change the value after http.post, look at my console after click, thanks :D

Comment: Whats the problem? The console.log(after) gets called before the http request came back... that's why you need to wrap it or do it in the callback...

Answer (score 1):

What about doing -

```
$scope.message = '';
$http.post('/save/').success(function(data) {                  
    $scope.message = "success";
    console.log($scope.message);
});
```

?

or am I missing something else?

Comment: no, i want to get $scope.message outside the http.post, can i?

Comment: In that case, look at my other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> why after i run, i get empty string on $scope.message?

The success callback for [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) is called asynchronously, when the response is available.  This explains why the console.log() can run before the callback.  If another function needs the value, @ShaiRez provided two solutions already:

1. call the other function inside the success callback
2. [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) the value, and call the other function inside the $watch listener callback