# Assigning a Value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have the following code in the services.js/Cordova

```
.factory('GCs', ['$http', function($http) {
        var obj= {};

        $http.post("mydomina.com?myrequest=getbyid", { "id": "1"} )
            .success(function(data) {
               obj= data; //there is a data returned correctly from the db
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                return null;
            });
            console.log(obj); //obj is undefined?
        return {
            all: function() {
              return obj;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

I am trying to return the json array (obj) from the database, however, this obj is **undefined** and thereby I am returning a null in the method **(all)** can anybody tell me the reason why?

Thanks

Comment: You're mixing an async call (.post() function) and a non-async statement (return something).

Comment: This code looks asynchronous. The `console.log` will be invoked before the `.success` callback. You may also be attempting to access the return value of `.all()` before the `.success` callback has finished.

Comment: the thing is when you try to echo the data, you will get the correct result from the database. But, in the console.log(obj) you will get undefined

Comment: @Riad do the `console.log(obj)` at the end of the `success` callback and you'll see your `obj` as expected

Comment: async call is ok to fetch the data from the database.. and I have to return something here because it's a factory

Comment: @PaulS. I Know, you're right but the thing is I want the all method in the return section to be able to see this obj

Comment: It can.. but you probably need to wait for it to become available.

Comment: sorry @PaulS. I miss understood you, what do you mean by to wait

Comment: (all) is a function inside the return section

Comment: Can you take a look at this post and see if it helps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580667/angular-how-to-return-value-from-http-post-success

Comment: Actually, no it won't... you're still trying to return something outside of the .post() function. NVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into issues where you're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. It's made slightly more complicated by the fact you're letting a variable used by the asynchronous callback be visible to external synchronous code.

Consider what is happening in this example code.

```
function foo() {
    var bar = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
        bar = true;
        console.log(bar); // logs true
    }, 1000);
    console.log(bar); // logs false
    return {
        buzz: function () {
            return bar;
        }
    };
}

// see what we have
var fizz = foo();
// immediately
console.log(fizz.buzz()); // logs false
// .. wait >1 second
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(fizz.buzz()); // logs true
}, 1500);
```

The `setTimeout` in `foo` here is similar to `.success` or `.error` in your code

So what are the solutions to your problem?

- Use your asynchronous callback to invoke subsequent pieces of code
- Fire an event from your callback and listen for that event before continuing with other pieces of code (you may have to implement a custom version of event listeners/handlers depending on your environment)

---

Here is an example of implementing events manually, it may be a bit overkill for your needs

```
function ObjectWithEvents(obj) {
    var handlers = Object.create(null);
    if (!obj) {
        if (this instanceof ObjectWithEvents) obj = this;
        else return new ObjectWithEvents();
    }
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'addEventListener', {
        value: function (type, handler) {
            if (!(type in handlers)) handlers[type] = [];
            handlers[type].push(handler);
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'removeEventListener', {
        value: function (type, handler) {
            var i;
            if (!(type in handlers)) return;
            i = handlers[type].indexOf(handler);
            if (i !== -1) handlers[type].splice(i, 1);
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'dispatchEvent', {
        value: function (e) {
            var i, j, frozen_handlers;
            if (!(e.type in handlers)) return;
            frozen_handlers = handlers[e.type].slice();
            j = frozen_handlers.length;
            for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
                frozen_handlers[i].call(this, e);
                // if (e.cancelled) return;
            }
        }
    });
}
ObjectWithEvents.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype);
```

And using it back with the `foo` example,

```
function foo() {
    var bar = false,
        ret_obj = new ObjectWithEvents();
    setTimeout(function () {
        bar = true;
        ret_obj.dispatchEvent({type: 'load'});
    }, 1000);
    ret_obj.buzz = function () {return bar;};
    return ret_obj;
}

var fizz = foo();

fizz.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(fizz.buzz()); // logs true
});
```

---

Here is a simplified example of how you might implement a callback in your current code

```
.factory('GCs', ['$http', function($http) {
        var obj= {};

        $http.post("mydomina.com?myrequest=getbyid", { "id": "1"} )
            .success(function(data) {
               obj = data;
               code_needing_obj();
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // throw something so you know why the code stopped
                return null;
            });
        return {
            all: function() {
              return obj;
            }
        };
    }]);

function code_needing_obj() {
    // accessing .all here will give you obj
    // etc
}
```

Or even re-organise your whole code so the http call is before everything

```
// make sure you have $http defined here
$http.post("mydomina.com?myrequest=getbyid", { "id": "1"} )
    .success(code_needing_obj) // this line lets invocation continue
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // throw something so you know why the code stopped
    });

function code_needing_obj(obj) {
    // ...
    .factory('GCs', ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                all: function() {
                  return obj;
                }
            };
        }]);
    // ...

}
```

Comment: Is it wrong to mix between the sync and async calls?

Comment: Could you please show me what do you mean on my code for the first solution? I am still newbie with angularjs

Comment: I tried to do something similar to the tab example like the following
<code>
.factory('Chats', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var chats = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Ben Sparrow',
    lastText: 'You on your way?',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/514549811765211136/9SgAuHeY.png'
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return chats;
    }
      return null;
    }
  }
  })</code>

Comment: but instead of having the chat json I am going to retrieve my json from the data base.. and then I will call the method all from the controller by saying $scope.Result = GCs.all(); where GCs is the name of the factory

Comment: I am trying the simplified example